# how to hide tabs in taskbar in windows xp

Tags: taskbar

how to hide tabs in taskbar in windows xp. 
Im already using vglance to emulate the windows 7 taskbar in xp. Is there any application that could hide the unused tabs(current downloads in firefox) And call it when you need it at a  later time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **[Taskbar Button Manager](http://www.innovative-sol.com/taskbar-button-manager/)** is a simple utility that helps you arrange
>   the buttons on your Windows taskbar in
>   any way you want by using drag and
>   drop. Moving your task buttons is very
>   easy, no hotkey needed. In addition to
>   drag and drop you can also use a
>   special program window for moving the
>   taskbar buttons. **You can hide
>   running programs too, so they don't
>   show on your taskbar.** The program
>   works in all situations – even when
>   the taskbar buttons are grouped or
>   when the taskbar is not located in the
>   standard bottom area of the screen.

*Taskbar Button Manager is freeware, registration required.*

p.s.: why don't you use grouping (taskbar properties)?